# How to calculate percent?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select

Could you help me to calculate percent of users, which made payments?
I've got two tables:

```
activity
user_id  login_time
201      01.01.2017
202      01.01.2017
255      04.01.2017
255      05.01.2017
256      05.01.2017
260      15.03.2017
```

## 2

```
payments
user_id  payment_date
200      01.01.2017
202      01.01.2017
255      05.01.2017
```

I try to use this query, but it calculates wrong percent:

```
SELECT activity.login_time, (select COUNT(distinct payments.user_id) 
from payments where payments.payment_time between '2017-01-01' and 
'2017-01-05') / COUNT(distinct activity.user_id) * 100
AS percent
FROM payments INNER JOIN activity ON  
activity.user_id = payments.user_id and activity.login_time between 
'2017-01-01' and '2017-01-05'
GROUP BY activity.login_time;
```

I need a result

```
01.01.2017  100 % 
02.01.2017  0% 
03.01.2017  0% 
04.01.2017  0% 
05.01.2017 - 50%
```

Comment: What results are you looking for?

Comment: Period of calculation is 01.01.2017 -05.01.2017

Comment: I need to calculate percent of users which made payments fron 01.01.17 until 05.01.17

Comment: I need a result

    01.01.2017 - 100 %
    02.01.2017 - 0%
    03.01.2017 - 0%
    04.01.2017 - 0%
    05.01.2017 - 50%

Answer (score 1):

If you want the ratio of users who have made payments to those with activity, just summarize each table individually:

```
select p.cnt / a.cnt
from (select count(distinct user_id) as cnt from activity a) a cross join
     (select count(distinct user_id) as cnt from payment) p;
```

EDIT:

You need a table with all dates in the range.  That is the biggest problem.

Then I would recommend:

```
SELECT d.dte,
       ( ( SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT p.user_id)
           FROM payments p
           WHERE p.payment_date >= d.dte and p.payment_date < d.dte + INTERVAL 1 DAY
          ) /
          NULLIF( (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT a.user_id)
                   FROM activity a
                   WHERE a.login_time >= d.dte and p.login_time < d.dte + INTERVAL 1 DAY
                  ), 0
                 ) as ratio
FROM (SELECT date('2017-01-01') dte UNION ALL
      SELECT date('2017-01-02') dte UNION ALL
      SELECT date('2017-01-03') dte UNION ALL
      SELECT date('2017-01-04') dte UNION ALL
      SELECT date('2017-01-05') dte 
     ) d;
```

Notes:

- This returns `NULL` on days where there is no activity.  That makes more sense to me than `0`.
- This uses logic on the dates that works for both dates and date/time values.
- The logic for dates can make use of an index, which can be important for this type of query.
- I don't recommend using `LEFT JOIN`s.  That will multiply the data which can make the query expensive.

Comment: thanks, it works. But what syntax can I use for time period from 01.01.17 until 05.01.07?
I need percent for each of these days.
I'll be grateful for answer

Comment: You just need a table (such as a calendar table) that has all the dates.  You can also list them all individually.

Answer (score 0):

First you need a table with all days in the range. Since the range is small you can build an ad hoc derived table using `UNION ALL`. Then left join the payments and activities. Group by the day and calculate the percentage using the `count()`s.

```
SELECT x.day,
       concat(CASE count(DISTINCT a.user_id)
                WHEN 0 THEN
                  1
                ELSE  
                  count(DISTINCT p.user_id)
                  /
                  count(DISTINCT a.user_id)
              END
              *
              100,
              '%')
       FROM (SELECT cast('2017-01-01' AS date) day
             UNION ALL
             SELECT cast('2017-01-02' AS date) day
             UNION ALL
             SELECT cast('2017-01-03' AS date) day
             UNION ALL
             SELECT cast('2017-01-04' AS date) day
             UNION ALL
             SELECT cast('2017-01-05' AS date) day) x
            LEFT JOIN payments p
                      ON p.payment_date = x.day
            LEFT JOIN activity a
                      ON a.login_time = x.day
            GROUP BY x.day;
```