# Calculate proportion (percent)

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join, select

Could you help me to calculate proportion of

```
Table
user_id    attendance   Date
1            1           01.01.2018
2            Null        01.01.2018
3            1           02.01.2018
4            Null        03.01.2018
5            1           03.01.2018
```

If user has attendance there is 1, otherwise - Null.

Need to calculate percent of attendance during 01.01.18 - 02.01.18.
For instance, on 01.01.2018 there were 1 user of two (50%), on 02.01.2018 - 100%.

Tnanks!

Comment: Is `01.01.2018` a literal string, or is it a date type?

Comment: This looks awfully like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52121144/how-to-calculate-percent

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen, it is date

Comment: Repeated question, check comments

Comment: If your attendance numbers could be something other than zero, then edit your question, add sample data, and explain it to us.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to calculate percent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52121144/how-to-calculate-percent)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this query:

```
SELECT
    Date,
    100.0 * COUNT(attendance) / COUNT(*) AS perc_attendance
FROM yourTable
WHERE Date BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-01-02'
GROUP BY
    Date;
```

This assumes that a given user would only appear at most once in attendance for a given date.  It also assumes that your `Date` column is an actual date column, and not just text.

[image]

### Demo

Comment: thanks! But how can I select only '1' from attendance?

Comment: `Need to calculate percent of attendance` ... did I misread your question, or did you ask the wrong question?

Comment: If I will have '2' and '1' instead of '1' and Null - what changes should I make into my query?

Comment: You don't need to change anything, actually, because `COUNT` counts any non NULL value as 1, and any NULL value as zero.  So my same answer should work if 1, 2, or any other number should appear.

Answer (score 0):

```
select v.date1 , case when s.no_people is null and v.showup_people then 100
when v.showup_people is null and s.no_people is not null then 0
else (v.showup_people / (v.showup_people + s.no_people))*100  end outcome 

from
(select count(*) as no_people , date as date1
   from yourTable
   where attendance is null
   group by date) s
   right outer join
   (select count(*) as showup_people , date as date1
   from yourTable
   where attendance is not null
   group by date) v
on(v.date1 = s.date1)
```

replace the from table to from your table name..

this will work always, no matter how many dates you have.
the case is because null + a number in mysql gives null.
in oracle sql you can just use the last else statment.

here is a [Demo](http://rextester.com/CIO51181)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query if you are trying to show as new table but then you must make one:

```
SELECT Date,100.0 * COUNT(attendance) / COUNT(*) AS attendancepercent
FROM Table WHERE Date BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-01-02'
GROUP BY Date;
```